# How can I set xdotool and gedit to open a document and save it twice?

Tags: scripts, gedit, xdotool

I need assistance in creating a script that does the following:

1. Open Gedit
2. Open a document with Gedit
3. Save the document twice
4. Close Gedit

I was wondering how can I make it happen with Gedit and xdotool, as xdotool can simulate the key combination to save a document <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+S

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The window must be focused because otherwise *gedit* will ignore X events sent by *xdotool*.

Here's what your script should be:

```
#!/bin/bash

gedit -s /path/to/document
# -s is standalone, meaning a new window will be opened instead of a tab in any existing gedit

sleep 5 # wait for gedit to open, adjust if necessary

GEDPID=$!  # save PID of gedit process

sleep 2 # wait for gedit to actually open document, adjust if necessary

GEDWINID=`xdotool search --pid $GEDPID | tail -1`
# gets window ID of gedit, the third "child" is the actual window

xdotool windowactivate --sync $GEDWINID key --clearmodifiers --delay 100 ctrl+s ctrl+s alt+F4
# focus gedit window, wait until focused, then save twice and exit
```